# How to use C++/TCL and C++/TK at the same time, in the same program?

Tags: c++, user-interface, function, tcl, tk-toolkit

So it is great of [C++/TCL](http://cpptcl.sourceforge.net/) to provide us with easy manageable in TCL C++ functions and classes via APIs like:

```
#include "cpptcl.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace Tcl;
void hello()
{
     cout << "Hello C++/Tcl!" << endl;
}
int main()
{
     interpreter i;
     i.def("hello", hello);
     string script = "for {set i 0} {$i != 4} {incr i} { hello }";
     i.eval(script);
}
```

At he same time its great to have an system event loop handled in [C++/Tk](http://cpptk.sourceforge.net/) with api's like

```
#include <string>
#include "cpptk.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string script = 
        "package require Tcl 8.5\n"
        "package require Tk 8.5\n"
        "ttk::button \".b\" -text \"Say Hello\"\n"
        "pack \".b\" -padx 20 -pady 6\n"
        ;
    Tk::details::Expr(script, true);
    Tk::runEventLoop();
}
```

So as you can see one is great for API creation another for GUI rendering.

I want to find a way to mix them to have for example such code working:

```
#include "cpptcl.h"
#include "cpptk.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace Tcl;
void hello()
{
     cout << "Hello C++/Tcl!" << endl;
}
int main()
{
     interpreter i;
     i.def("hello", hello);
     string script = 
        "package require Tcl 8.5\n"
        "package require Tk 8.5\n"
        "ttk::button \".b\" -text \"Say Hello\" -command hello \n"
        "pack \".b\" -padx 20 -pady 6\n"
        ;
    Tk::details::Expr(script, true);
    Tk::runEventLoop();
}
```

How to do such thing possible? How to mix C++/TCL and C++/Tk?

***Updete:***

And so we have done it. Required some CPP/TCL and CPP/Tk sorurce code fixing, see [our svn](http://cloudobserver.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CloudClient/src/3rdparty/), and [my answer for example of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587082/how-to-use-c-tcl-and-c-tk-at-the-same-time-in-the-same-programm/6589766#6589766).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UI callbacks to do complicated things, including running other Tcl code:

```
#include "cpptcl.h"
#include "cpptk.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace Tcl;

class TclHost
{
  interpreter i;
  static TclHost* singleton;

  static void hello()
  {
     cout << "Hello C++/Tcl!" << endl;
  }

  static void runScript()
  {
     singleton->i.def("hello", &TclHost::hello);
     string script = "for {set i 0} {$i != 4} {incr i} { hello }";
     singleton->i.eval(script);
  }

public:
  int main()
  {
     singleton = this;
     i.def("runscript", &TclHost::runScript);
     string script = 
        "package require Tcl 8.5\n"
        "package require Tk 8.5\n"
        "ttk::button \".b\" -text \"Run a script\" -command runscript\n"
        "pack \".b\" -padx 20 -pady 6\n"
        ;
    Tk::details::Expr(script, true);
    Tk::runEventLoop();

    return 0;
  }
};

TclHost* TclHost::singleton;

int main(void)
{
  TclHost().main();
}
```

You'll also want to look at other callbacks, including timers and file I/O, that the Tcl/Tk event loop supports.

Comment: I'm not sure that'll work; I *think* you'll end up with two Tcl interpreter contexts at once, neither of which will be able to interact with the other (the problem being that C++/Tk locks its interpreter handle away pretty deep and you'd need to find some way to make C++/Tcl use that same handle as the core of its interpreter class). It'd be pretty neat if it did work though.

Comment: So.. I get Error 1 error C3867: 'TclHost::hello': function call missing argument list; use '&TclHost::hello' to create a pointer to member c:\users\avesta\documents\файлы mail.ru агента\superior0@mail.ru\fchunovkin@mail.ru\mix\src\tcltktest.cpp 19 1 CppTkDemo
and Error 2 error C3867: 'TclHost::runScript': function call missing argument list; use '&TclHost::runScript' to create a pointer to member c:\users\avesta\documents\файлы mail.ru агента\superior0@mail.ru\fchunovkin@mail.ru\mix\src\tcltktest.cpp 26 1 CppTkDemo
triying to compile code as you presented

Comment: And I get "invalid command name "runscript" " (tcl window) if I turn yours structure into application.  "invalid command name "runscript"
invalid command name "runscript"
    while executing
"runscript"
    invoked from within
".b invoke "
    invoked from within
".b instate {pressed !disabled} { .b state !pressed; .b invoke } "
    (command bound to event)" details

Comment: @Kabumbus: How about this?  @Donal: That's why I moved the interpreter instance into a class... I don't want it initialized too early as a global would be, but I do want it shared with the callbacks.

Comment: Error 1 error C4716: 'TclHost::main' : must return a value c:\users\avesta\documents\файлы mail.ru агента\superior0@mail.ru\fchunovkin@mail.ru\mix\src\tcltktest.cpp 37 1 CppTkDemo

Comment: Error 2 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals C:\Users\Avesta\Documents\Файлы Mail.Ru Агента\superior0@mail.ru\fchunovkin@mail.ru\Mix\projects\windows-vs2010\bin\debug\CppTkDemo.exe 1 1 CppTkDemo and Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class TclHost * TclHost::singleton" (?singleton@TclHost@@0PAV1@A) C:\Users\Avesta\Documents\Файлы Mail.Ru Агента\superior0@mail.ru\fchunovkin@mail.ru\Mix\projects\windows-vs2010\TclTkTest.obj CppTkDemo

Comment: @Kabumbus: So true.  Fixed that also.

Comment: I actually found a way and soon will post it on public svn., and create some note about it here. so stay tuned - its actually 10 lines of code additions to cpptk (cpptkbase) files and you can get mixed cpptcl and cpptk code in no time=)

Comment: @BenVoigt let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1164/discussion-between-kabumbus-and-ben-voigt)

Comment: BTW: thank you wary, wary much for your code sample and effort.=)

Answer (score 0):

So [we have done it...) here is our svn with updated, working C++/Tk and C++/TCL](http://cloudobserver.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CloudClient/src/3rdparty/), patched for work with each other, corrected from some errors that were on official sourceforge site.

And here is code sample inspired [by Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587082/how-to-use-c-tcl-and-c-tk-at-the-same-time-in-the-same-programm/6587460#6587460):

```
#include "cpptcl/cpptcl.h"
#include "cpptk/cpptk.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
Tcl::interpreter i(Tk::getInterpreter());
void hello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello C++/Tcl!" << std::endl;
}
void runScript()
{
    i.def("hello", hello);
    std::string script = "for {set i 0} {$i != 4} {incr i} { hello }";
    i.eval(script);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    i.def("runscript", runScript);
    std::string script = 
        "package require Tcl 8.5\n"
        "package require Tk 8.5\n"
        "ttk::button \".b\" -text \"Say Hello\" -command hello \n"
        "ttk::button \".c\" -text \"Run a script\" -command runscript\n"
        "pack \".b\" -padx 20 -pady 6\n"
        "pack \".c\" -padx 20 -pady 6\n"
        ;
    i.eval(script);
    Tk::runEventLoop();
}
```

Have a good luck in using TCL and Tk!)

Answer (score 0):

```
Tcl::interpreter i(Tk::getInterpreter());

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    i.def("runscript", runScript);
    std::string script = 
        "package require Tcl 8.5\n"
        "package require Tk 8.5\n"
        "ttk::button \".b\" -text \"Say Hello\" -command hello \n"
        "ttk::button \".c\" -text \"Run a script\" -command runscript\n"
        "pack \".b\" -padx 20 -pady 6\n"
        "pack \".c\" -padx 20 -pady 6\n"
        "after 10 vwait qwerasdfzxcv\n"
        ;
    i.eval(script);
    //Tk::runEventLoop(); //<== if you don't want stock here to make mainthread can keep running. you can add tcl script "after 10 vwait qwerasdfzxcv" as above showed.
```

}